# How to allow user to upload files to website?

Tags: web-development-server

I have a website written in HTML/CSS/Vanilla JS and I'd like to add a form for users to upload pictures and text to the root folder. Seems like a mundane task but I can't find any information on this. What technologies should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you get into the territory of backend development: You can (for example) use an HTML `<input type="file">` to select a file and send it as part of a form, but you will need a server to handle your request. There is a plethora of languages to write backend servers in, some popular ones are node (server-side JS) and PHP.

[Here's a tutorial page for file uploads in PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

[And one for file uploads in Node using Express.js](https://attacomsian.com/blog/uploading-files-nodejs-express)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `<input type="text"/>` and  `<input type="file"/>`, you can make users input both text and files (pictures for your case).

Now, for saving this information in your file, you should use **php** or some other server side technology.

PHP Approach : https://www.allphptricks.com/upload-file-using-php-save-directory/

For Just texts : [How can I save my form data to a local text file using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102826/how-can-i-save-my-form-data-to-a-local-text-file-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can check this out, I hope it will work, and kindly, make sure that create one folder to store uploaded videos.

file 1 -> config.php
<?php

```
$host = "localhost";    /* Host name */
$user = "root";         /* User */
$password = "admin";         /* Password */
$dbname = "mydb";   /* Database name */

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

file 2 -> index.php which will the main page of the file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php
        include("config.php");
     
        if(isset($_POST['but_upload'])){
            $maxsize = 10000000; // 5MB
                       
            $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $target_dir = "https://mmcollegebihiya.in/form1/videos/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

            // Select file type
            $videoFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            // Valid file extensions
            $extensions_arr = array("mp4","avi","3gp","mov","mpeg");

            // Check extension
            if( in_array($videoFileType,$extensions_arr) ){
                
                // Check file size
                if(($_FILES['file']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["file"]["size"] == 0)) {
                    echo "File too large. File must be less than 5MB.";
                }else
                {
                    // Upload
                    //if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_file)){
                        // Insert record
                        $query = "INSERT INTO videos(name,location) VALUES('".$name."','".$target_file."')";

                        mysqli_query($con,$query);
                        echo "Upload successfully.";
                    //}
                }

            }else{
                echo "Invalid file extension.";
            }
        }
        
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='file' />
            <input type='submit' value='Upload' name='but_upload'>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

File 3 -> Checking videos php

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            video{
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
          
        <?php
        $fetchVideos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchVideos)){
            $location = $row['location'];
            
            echo "<div >";
            echo "<video src='".$location."' controls width='320px' height='200px' >";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        ?>
          
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

If this will not work, then I will share other code too, but don't mark -1 .